# Is it safe to put 195/65/R15 winter tires instead of 205/65/R15 on Civic'17?

Tags: tires, civic, winter

According to the dealership official down-size for Honda Civic'17 is 205/65/R15  (stock tire size is 215/55/R16), but I have 195/65/R15 winters from a previous year Civic.

I understand that 195 tires will set off the speedometer slightly, since they are about 1/2'' shorter.

What I am wondering is if there chance of damaging the car with these slightly smaller tires, or can I get through the winter with light use (say 5,000k)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all four tyres are the same size, your car won't know anything's different. You'll just have a tiny bit extra accleration :)

Don't sweat it. As long as the tyres fit the rims properly.

Comment: To follow up: driving with these smaller tires for second season now. Speedometer shows about 3km/h faster than reality (checked with road speed displays).